# Ninject with ria domainservice standard asp.net webapplication

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject, ria

I would like to use DI (Ninject) with my RIA webservices which is located on a standard asp.net webserver.

How should I hook up my repositories containing the datastore?

I've added a Global.asax file :

```
    public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IPersonRepository>().To<PersonRepository>();
        Application.Add("Kernel", kernel);
        return kernel;
    }
```

And here's where I would like to hook it up,...but I'm stuck

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class PersonService : DomainService
{
    IPersonRepository _personRepository;        

    public PersonService()
    {    
             _personRepository = ????....kernel.Get<IPersonRepository>();

    }
}
```

It seems that I'm only missing a way to get the application object and then it would work, or?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience of RIA Web Services per se, but after a quick scan of the documentation I would suggest doing the following. Create an implementation of [IDomainServiceFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.idomainservicefactory.createdomainservice%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) for Ninject.

```
public class NinjectDomainServiceFactory : IDomainServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectDomainServiceFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public DomainService CreateDomainService(
        Type domainServiceType, DomainServiceContext context)
    {
        var service = _kernel.Get(domainServiceType);
        service.Initialize(context);

        return service;
    }

    public void ReleaseDomainService(DomainService domainService)
    {
        domainService.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Register the custom domain service factory with the [DomainService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.domainservice_members%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) class in Application_Start.

```
public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var kernel = CreateKernel();
    DomainService.Factory = new NinjectDomainServiceFactory(kernel);
}
```

Make sure you register your domain services and any dependencies with the kernel. The IPersonRepository should be injected in the constructor of the PersonService.

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class PersonService : DomainService
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository;        

    public PersonService(IPersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will be helpful as I haven't tried the solution myself.